# Error using In-Page Analytics report in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, redirects, error

We are unable to use the In-Page Analytics report in Google Analytics because our site now redirects to a URL which is different from what is in our Account setting.  Are there any workarounds which will give us the In-Page Analytics and not impact our history data?

Comment: Is the site being redirected to, a different design/layout than the old one because if so, what's the use of In Page analytics in GA going to be?

Comment: Hi Geoff. The site itself did not change. we just changed the url so the business name could be seen. Before we had an abbreviation so it was not helping branding.

Comment: So when you switched to a new domain, didn't you create a new property for it in Google Analytics? So that you'd have data for the new domain and data for the old domain...

Comment: we actually did create a new property but the site redirects to a different dommain

Comment: If in-page analytics is going to follow the redirect then this is a limitation of GA unfortantely - I do have one possible workaround which is a bit of work and untested though. I'll post my answer. (Although if the website design/layout is the same, I don't see why you can't still just use the in-page analytics it shows you as it matches this against URL paths so if these haven't changed, it should still work and be accurate for what you want).

Answer (score 1):

All I can really suggest is duplicating the website at another location but minus the domain redirect so that you can use this to view past in-page analytics on the old website.

- Purchase a new domain and set up the web hosting.
- Duplicate the website on this new domain and database.
- Make sure you  [NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) the duplicated website.
- Stop the redirect on this duplicated website so it does not redirect to your other domain.
- Password protect the domain with `.htaccess`. ([Learn how here](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/)).
- Create
- Modify your GA property to track with the same UA on both domains. ([Learn how here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en-GB)).

Come to think of it actually, I'm not even sure in-page analytics in GA will give you an option to show for different domains (even though GA supports cross-domain tracking). Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer is no. The answer provided by @zigojack will work.

Thing is, is it worth going through all the trouble? In-Page analytics is there for convenience and at times can be misleading.

You have a wealth of information inside your GA account so I would just use that.